# linux, freepascal, fp-ide: No debugger support availble. How to enable debugger?

Tags: linux, freepascal

How to enable debugger in fp-ide? I read somewhere that I should compile fp-ide from sources, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: You might also want to state which distribution you use. For Ubuntu I can imagine there might be a PPA with `fp-ide` precompiled.

Comment: ubuntu, Can you explain how to make this?

Comment: I'd recommend to use a different IDE, [lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) is a really versatile IDE for FreePascal programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the generic linux tar installer (fpc-2.6.0.x86_64-linux.tar) for FPC from http://www.freepascal.org/down/x86_64/linux-hungary.var It comes with a precompiled IDE with integrated debugger support and it works fine at least on 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a PPA for `fp-ide`, but I can describe how the CLI IDE is compiled on Arch Linux as documented in the [repository](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/fpc). Do note that compiling will not enable the debugger in the CLI, as it seems to be an incompatibility between `gdb` and `fp` (fp-ide) according to e.g. [this bug report in Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=528855). On Arch Linux, the `fpc` package also doesn't support the debugger in `fp` by design (it is explicitly disabled using the `NOGDB` flag).

Anyhow, here goes the compilation process:

1. Make sure you have FreePascal installed already, as you need it to compile the IDE
2. Download the [source tarball](ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/dist/2.6.0/source/fpcbuild-2.6.0.tar.gz)
3. Extract the tarball to a location of your convenience and `cd` into that directory

Execute the following code from within your shell:

```
pushd fpcsrc/compiler
fpcmake -Tall
popd
make build          
make -j1 install    
# in Arch, the switch "NOGDB=1" is present in both make lines
```

That should compile the IDE and install it (you can even try to integrate it in `dpkg` by using [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of `make install`, but take a look at the [Arch PKGBUILD](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/fpc) to see an example of what might be needed).

But why do you use the command line IDE `fp` instead of `lazarus`? With [`lazarus`](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) you can also make console applications and it offers much more features (e.g. working debug support).

Comment: I am competing in informatics olympiads and lazarus is't so comfortable for me to writing solutions. Thank you for instruction. It is compiling FP-IDE. I hope it would be fast. I will notify about results

Comment: Should I add "NOGDB=1" or not? Without "NOGDB=1", IDE says the same.

Comment: I guess `NOGDB=1` turns off support for the `gdb`. You could try with `nogdb=0` or without mentioning it at all; but I doubt it would result in a stable environment. Also make sure you execute the newly-compiled binary and not the old one.

Comment: FP-IDE don't want to compile with gdb support. At first it asked libgdb.a.. I install libgdb. Then when I try to compile it, IDE said http://pastebin.com/n50sxbgW